# Changed keyboard, now can't enter password

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, locked-out, sony-xperia-z

For some reason, I changed my keyboard to Greek, yet my password is in English. I am unable to enter the password to unlock the phone. I can't pair with Bluetooth without unlocking, and there is no option to change the language of the keyboard. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the built-in keyboard's language, or did you install, activate, and switch to a 3rd-party keyboard?  Also, it would help to know which Android OS version you have installed, and if the device is rooted.

Comment: The device is not rooted. It is the default keyboard's language that I changed, so it stays there in safe mode, its on 4.4 KitKat and it's a Sony xperia z.

Comment: Does it not allow you to enter your gmail password after a few failed attempts? But i assume you are unable to type that either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android device manager to get past your password, then you will be able to access menus and change the language.

Answer (score 1):

You can Hack the screenlock password by typing this from terminal:

```
$ adb shell
$ rm /data/system/gesture.key
```

Comment: But I'm not in USB Debugging mode.